# VS code annoying pop up

Tags: visual-studio-code

I am using VS code to do my development.

Can anyone help me to get rid of this annoying popup.

I get the following popup.

[image: VS popup]

This info pop up get triggered every time when i open the VS code editor,
Even if i click Don't show again i am getting this pop up again everytime when i reopen the VS code.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried installing the Python extension?

Comment: it again throw me a error cannot read property 'panel' of undefined when i hit install/show recommendations